# LOV on Interactive Report Oracle Apex 5

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Good day All.
I know in Oracle Apex 4 there use to be a way to select the "Display As" for a report. I however can not for the like of me find anything similar in Apex 5.

What I am trying to achieve is to get results of a table in Oracle. Then display the default calues, but one of the values in the report must be selectable to show a list of values.

```
  select "Name", Serial, Description, status from table order by 1;
```

which will return:

```
  Server01 | ABC123 | Print Server | Commissioned
  Server02 | DEF456 | File  Server | Commissioned
```

Another Status table will contain:

```
  Status_ID  | Status_Name
     1A      | Commissioned
     1D      | Decommissioned
```

So when the table displays, it needs to show the default values as per the return above with commissioned being the default value, but each row should contain a dropdown so the user can then select the new value if needed, but the new values will be selected from the Status view. Once all values are set, the submit will update the table.

any help will be great!

Comment: If you're generating the list item using `apex_item`, you would set the column type to `Plain Text` and set `Escape special characters` to No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my own problem with a work around. I had to use a tabular form instead. For some reason it is not working with Interactive reports.

Thanks!